# SSIS Delete then Insert: Incompatible transaction context was specified for a retained connection

Tags: transactions, ssis

I'm developing an SSIS-package that has to query (execute SPs) a Source Database for Generations, and then insert those Generations into a Destination Database.

For this, I need to make a couple of checks: does the Generation from the Source DB already exist in the Destination DB? If not, just insert it. If it does exist, was it updated since the last time it was inserted (aka: does LastModified differ from the same generation in the DestinationDB)? If not, just leave it be. If so, update the Generation in the Destination DB.

The problem I'm facing has to do with the related data. Not only the Generation has to be inserted, but every related item has to be inserted in the Destination's tables as well (e.g. Equipment, Packs, ...).

Since the Destination DB is a read-only DB, this was easily accomplished by a delete of the generation (which cascades to the other tables), and then insert the generation again. Everything worked fine.

Now, the next step is to include transactions in this workflow (when I delete something, I have to insert the new data. If that fails, everything needs to be rolled back). I've set the package's isolation level to Serializable, and the TransactionOption to Required. The DestinationConnection has RetainSameConnection set to True.

Whenever I try to debug my package with the same data that worked before, I get the following error message:

> Incompatible transaction context was specified for a retained
>   connection. This connection has been established under a different
>   transaction context. Retained connections can be used under exactly
>   one transaction context.

In my opinion, this is because I try to delete all data, and then reinsert it in the same transaction. SSIS probably wants to use different connections (RetainSameConnection set to False solves the problem), but that's not what I had in mind, unless one connection that fails makes the other one rollback too (but I've read that this isn't the case...).

Can anyone help pointing me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to setting RetainSameConnection property of my connection to false. I figured I needed all of it to run on the same connection, but apparently, this is not the case. Rollbacks seem to work even without the components running on the same connection constantly.

Grtz